# Unix: Using date in alias doesn't output the current date/time

Tags: unix, date, time, command, alias

In my bash_profile, I'm referencing an external alias.sh file, which has the following alias:

```
alias date="echo `date "+%Y-%m-%d at %H:%M":%S`"
```

If I issue `date` in a new terminal session, it constantly outputs the specific date at the time when the alias.sh file was sourced (i.e. when I started the new session) …

How do I make an alias that actually outputs the ***current*** date, when executing the aliased command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uhh, why not just?

```
alias date='date "+%Y-%m-%d at %H:%M":%S'
```

No need to echo it. When you use the backwards tick ( ` ), whatever's in it gets evaluated when alias.sh is sourced.

Answer (score 2):

you can place a backslash character in front of each backquote character. :

```
sysadmin@localhost:~$ alias p=\'date\'
sysadmin@localhost:~$ p  
Tue Apr  4 13:17:57 UTC 2017 
sysadmin@localhost:~$ echo Today is $(p)                                        
Today is Tue Apr 4 13:19:18 UTC 2017
```

Answer (score -2):

Add this to your `~/.aliases` file:

```
alias cd 'cd \!* ; set prompt = "\n`/bin/pwd`\n:%{^[];%~^G%}%{^[[0;37m%}(%{^[[1;36m%}%p%{^[[0;37m%})%{^[[0;35m%}%m%{^[[0;37m%}%{^[[0;33m%}>%{^[[0;37;37m%}:\n`/usr/bin/whoami`>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> "'
```

Then run `$source ~/.aliases`